# AWS Windows Powershell ECR Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, aws-powershell, aws-ecr

I am new to AWS and Docker. I am trying to setup AWS ECR and docker and trying to retrieve ECR Login using windows powershell. I am trying to use the command -

> Invoke-Expression -Command (aws ecr get-login)
>   which gives me the error[image]

My problem is it is trying to use the ccuser on its own. I don't think I have configured it to use this user. I have created a separate user with AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess. How do I configure this as the user for AWS Powershell to execute the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws ecr get-login` will simply use the creds that you've already setup for the AWS CLI. If you want to change the creds for the CLI, use `aws configure` to do the setup again, it will ask you for:

`AWS Access Key ID []: 
AWS Secret Access Key []: 
Default region name []: 
Default output format []:`

If you only want to use that user temporarily without reconfiguring your existing account, [here are the docs for doing that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

simple and easy, I was debugging this for while but somehow it worked

> aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ecr.amazonaws.com